# C# passing Single as reference

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I would like to have a method where the parameter could be `Int32` or `Single`:

```
void myMethod( ref object x )
{
     //...CodeHere
}
```

Since C# does not allow me to pass a specialization of object when using `out` or `ref`, the solution I found claimed that assigning the variable to a variable of the type `object` would be enough:

```
Single s = 1.0F;
object o = s;
myMethod( ref o );
```

That didn't work. According to the Microsoft documentation I looked at, `o` should be a pointer to `s`. The sources I looked at state that assigning non-primitive types generate a reference and not a `new` instance.

Is it possible to have a method where I can pass `Single` or `Int32` or any other type that is a specialization of `object`?

Comment: You misread whatever boxing documentation you had in front of you. It generated a boxed instance to a copy of the original value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Overload the method:

```
void myMethod( ref int x )
{
    //...
}

void myMethod(ref single x)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: My first fix to this proble was exactly this, but I thought that should be another way. This problem seems to be specific with Single and related. Complex classes do not suffer from this limitation.
Anyway, if no other solution appears, I will use your suggestion.
thanks

Comment: Flavio: the reason this isn't working the way you think it should has to do with the fact that ints and floats are Value Types, while object is a Reference Type. I suggest you read up on the difference. Here's a nice start ( http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx ), but I suggest you spend an hour or two googling the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're out of luck. You'll be better off using two methods:

```
void MyMethod(ref float x)
{
  //....
}

void MyMethod(ref int x)
{
  //....
}
```

Comment: Actually, Joel beat me by 3 seconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to have a method where the parameter could be Int32 or Single"

How about using a [Generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(VS.80).aspx) instead?

NB:  In the current version of C# you can only be able to constrain the allowable types to struct not specific types such as int, float.

Comment: You couldn't constrain the generic parameter to be only `int` or `float` though. The closest you could get would be restricting it to `struct`, which would allow lots of other types to slip in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of boxing the value in an object, you could overload the function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        static int test = 0;

        static void MyMethod(int arg)
        {
            test += arg;
        }

        static void MyMethod(ref int arg)
        {
            test += arg;
        }

        static void MyMethod(Single arg)
        {
            test += Convert.ToInt32(arg);
        }

        static void MyMethod(ref Single arg)
        {
            test += Convert.ToInt32(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

What you do with the argument inside the methods is dependent on what you're trying to accomplish, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use Ash's approach and go with a generic implementation along the following lines:

```
    static void myMethod<T>(ref T value) where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>
    {
        value = (T)Convert.ChangeType(value.ToSingle(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) * 2.0, typeof(T));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int data1 = 5;

        myMethod(ref data1);
        if (data1 != 10)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        Single data2 = 1.5f;

        myMethod(ref data2);
        if (data2 != 3)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
```